# How Jira self-hosted limit the users

Tags: jira

I tried to setup selt-hosted jira on my server (trial version). I can control the database (insert, update, delete...) and I can add a new user. So which mechanism Jira use for limit the user on self-hosted license ?

Answer (score 0):

Trial (evaluation) licenses have unlimited users, I think? A commercial license has a limit encoded in it. If you have more than that many users then Jira won't let you create new issues. I don't recommend adding users via the DB due to the fiddly way that autoincrement of row ids is implemented

Comment: You mean even using a commercial license I can still add users through the DB and restricting users by license doesn't work

Comment: I don't recommend making any changes in Jira directly in the database.